# jQuery this selector not available to animate() method properies

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, this

Can someone explain to me why the "this" selector is not available to the animate() methods properties.

See the 1st example at http://jsfiddle.net/qZVv4/, there are no errors produced it just ignores it.

```
 $('#test1 .bar[data-percentage]').animate({
     width: $(this).attr('data-percentage'),
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
 }, 1000, function () {
     $(this).text($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` isn't referring to your element. You're still in the same scope, so `this` doesn't change. You'd have to do something like this instead:

```
// You need the easing plugin
// https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing

$('#test1 .bar[data-percentage]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.animate({
        width: $this.data('percentage')
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        //easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        step: function(value) {
            $(this).text(value + '%');
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qZVv4/4/**

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only has function scope, the `this` in your example is not in the callback function, it is just referring to the `window` object.